# About business rules that have calculations

Tags: documentation, uml, artifacts

I'm documenting a system with many calculations in their business rules. To represent these calculations I don't know what kind of artifact I need to generate to clarify these rules and their calculations.

What do you suggest to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just setup a plain document (e.g. latex)
2. ...and include all formulas you need. Encapsulate them into (uniquely numbered) requirements.
3. Assign clear and unique names to your calculations and
4. refer to them in the UML activity diagrams, state charts, class method names or whatever else you need as artifacts.

You'll probably be faster that way than forcing everything into your diagrams. They're meant to make life easier for you and others, after all ;)

Comment: I like you approach. The very only problem is latex. Not all users knows that and for maintenance it's not a good idea. Steps 2, 3 and 4 I'll use certainly but with Excel.

Comment: Thank you. I'll certainly not force anyone to use latex :) It really is just an example. As you rightly indicate, Office can do a very good job here, too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Object Constraint Language (OCL) to express such things. You could attach a calculation expressed in OCL to a derived attribute.

Comment: ...but keep in mind that tool support for OCL is quite poor / basic.

Comment: Exactly, and is not for all stakeholders in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I Think business rules mostly implies the way your system has to respond to inputs or events. That means most of rules are used to describe what would be the reaction of your system if certain situation happens. We can describe these type of facts using artifacts like state chart or activity diagrams (as high level).

Also a spreadsheet software (like Microsoft Excel) could be used to describe detailed calculation of a rule or a Use-Case of your system. They are widespread, easily maintainable and everyone can access the calculations and event the sample results. Even some business rule engines (like JBoss DRool) take your business rules in spreadsheet file as input, interpret them and infer the correct decisions from them.

Comment: Right, I'll mix your idea with @observer observations.